# Click event triggered two times when gazing to an object

Tags: aframe, gaze-buttons

I'm using gaze buttons but when the click event is triggered, the function is executed two times. See code snippet below.

```js
var number = 0;

document.getElementsByTagName('a-sphere')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('You\'ve clicked the sphere ' + (++number) + ' times.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
    <!-- this is my object that must execute a click event when looked -->
    <a-sphere position="0 0 -7" color="red">
    </a-sphere>

    <!-- camera -->
    <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <!-- progress bar -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 -3" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.07;radiusInner: 0.05;" material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
            cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
            <!--<a-cursor color="red"></a-cursor>-->
            <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
            <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
        </a-entity>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

How could I prevent this situation of two times clicking on an object? It must be triggered just one time when it's clicked.

Comment: Are you testing/previewing on desktop? Because the drag-to-move will trigger a click.

Comment: @ngokevin: Yes, I'm testing on desktop. PS: There is an snippet added in my question where you could test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround to prevent this issue

```js
var number = 0;

document.getElementsByTagName('a-sphere')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.getAttribute('data-clicked') === null || this.getAttribute('data-clicked') === 'false') {
        this.setAttribute('data-clicked', 'true');
        alert('You\'ve clicked the sphere ' + (++number) + ' times.');
    }
    else {
        this.setAttribute('data-clicked', 'false');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
    <!-- this is my object that must execute a click event when looked -->
    <a-sphere position="0 0 -7" color="red">
    </a-sphere>

    <!-- camera -->
    <a-camera look-controls wasd-controls cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
        <!-- progress bar -->
        <a-entity position="0 0 -3" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.07;radiusInner: 0.05;" material="color: cyan; shader: flat"
            cursor="maxDistance: 30; fuse: true">
            <!--<a-cursor color="red"></a-cursor>-->
            <a-animation begin="click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="backwards" from="0.1 0.1 0.1" to="1 1 1" dur="150"></a-animation>
            <a-animation begin="fusing" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" fill="forwards" from="1 1 1" to="0.1 0.1 0.1" dur="1500"></a-animation>
        </a-entity>
    </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Of course this is not a good way of preventing the issue, but it's working.